# Upload failed when I publish Moodle app on google play store?

Tags: android, moodle-mobile

I get this exception when I publish Moodle app to play sore, how can I fix these errors?

> Upload failed You uploaded a debuggable APK.
>
> For security reasons you
> need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.
> Learn more about debuggable APKs. You uploaded an APK that was signed
> in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more
> about signing. You need to use a different package name because
> "com.moodle.moodlemobile" already exists in Google Play.

Thanks

Comment: How are you signing your .apk?

Comment: I didnt sign it. I am using cordova to build the app.

Comment: That's the problem, you cannot publish not signed applications on Google Play

Comment: how can I sign it by ionic or cordova?

Comment: I followed the commands here and it works http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You .apk must be signed so you can publish it on Google Play. For sign your .apk follow the links bellow:

For **Cordoba** platform: http://ilee.co.uk/Sign-Releases-with-Cordova-Android/

For **Ionic** platform: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Comment: Thank you, that works with me, I just still need to know how  I can change the package name  "com.moodle.moodlemobile"

Comment: I changed it in the config.xml, and it is ok :)

Comment: @DevMaillano  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate signed apk after your app will publish.

Follow this link generate signed apk :

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html